# Quickblox messages mixing if first time chat in android

Tags: chat, quickblox

I have implemented quickblox sdk 2.2 version in android,  but there is problem that.

If I have registered three Users suppose User A, B, C at same time and I am creating private chat between three users but at first time  if there is chat converstion between user A and  user B at that time if user C message to User A than chat converstion between A and B stop at same chat window and start chat between User A and User C . I need support for this query.

Thanks
Please give any solution to me

Comment: Please show what you have tried to give us an idea of what direction you are going with this.

Comment: Please check this link    http://quickblox.com/developers/Android

Comment: Well that's hard to understand what is going on here... Please provide some code samples and more info in a clearer way